# Get input from serial port (RS-232)

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port

im writing a program which reads the input from the serial port. It does recieve something but its breaking the line without reason.

**The right input**

This right inout should be

```
Sending...Sending...Sending...Sending...Sending...
```

Without changing line.

**The actual input**

```
Sending...
Se
ndin
g...
S
endi
ng..
.
Send
ing.
..
Se
ndin
g...
```

**The code**

```
public void Serial ()
    {
        try
        {
            SerialPort serial = new SerialPort(this.comboBox1.Text);

            serial.BaudRate = 9600;
            serial.Parity = Parity.None;
            serial.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serial.DataBits = 8;
            serial.Handshake = Handshake.None;

            serial.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(SerialDataReceivedHandler);

            serial.Open();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    public void SerialDataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) 
    {
        SerialPort sp = (SerialPort)sender;
        string dataIn = sp.ReadExisting();
        if (log_time == true) 
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(time + dataIn);
        }
        else
        {
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(dataIn + "\n");
        }

    }
```

The `this.combobox1.Text` is working fine, im using try because if not the program would crash if the serial port wasnt on!

Im initializing the serial on an other void with `Serial();`

How can i get the right input?

Answer (score 0):

In your else clause, you should not append "\n" to this.richTextBox1. That is the special character for a new line. If you want the right input, need something like `this.richTextBox1.AppendText(dataIn + "...");`